# Modal form loses control box functionality when displayed on a secondary monitor

Tags: c#, modal-dialog

I have exactly the same problem as described in this article:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winforms/thread/bb67bf2d-4f6b-49a1-a107-18b11520bf8e

Can anyone provides some ideas? Thanks a lot!

Copied from the above link:

> *If I display the form as modal using `ShowDialog`, it displays on my primary monitor, and behaves nicely there (maximize, minimize, etc...).*
>
> *If I move the form on a second or a third monitor, and then maximizes
>   it, the whole bar above stops working: from left (system menu) to
>   right (restore or minimize or close), including the middle (double
>   click on the bar does not restore).*
>
> *In some cases, the mouse cursor changes to "size" when I go over the
>   form bar. And left-clicking and moving does resize the form!*

Comment: could you show some code, because simple modal form works OK

Comment: There is a sample code list in http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winforms/thread/bb67bf2d-4f6b-49a1-a107-18b11520bf8e. I have similar code runs on windows XP and got the exact problem when app suns on secondary monitor. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As they observed on the msdn site in the above link, it happens if your second monitor is configured to the left of your main monitor, but not when it's on the right.

This happens in VS2010 and VS2012, both C# and VB.NET.

1) Create a Windows Form application

2) Add a button to the form

3) For the button click handler for the button code this:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form f = new Form();
        f.ShowDialog();
    }
```

4) Run the app, click the button.  Drag the 2nd form to another monitor, and maximize.

5) All of the title bar buttons:  Minimize, Restore/Maximize, Close are now disabled, though you can
   restore via the right-click context menu.   Maximizing on the main monitor doesn't do this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the second screen at the left until I changed the `Form.FormBorderStyle` property to `FixedSingle` or `Fixed3D` or `FixedDialog`.
This property can de changed in the `Form_SizeChanged` event handler like this :

```
Private Sub Form1_SizeChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.SizeChanged
        If Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized Then
            Me.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.Fixed3D
else
            Me.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.Sizable
End if
```